Flutter: Cómo ejecutar el método de un StatefulWidget desde un StatelessWidget
gracias por leer.
Quiero hacer el mítico icono de la campanita y que vibre cuando llegue una notificación. Las animaciones las estoy haciendo con la libreía de animate_do
Tengo un StatelessWidget como screen, y dentro de este, llamo al StetatefulWidget:
Screen (StetelessWidget):
import 'package:animate_do/animate_do.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_demo_app/modules/animations/widgets/notification_icon_animation.dart';
import 'package:my_demo_app/shared/presentation/widgets/app_drawer.dart';

class AnimationsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimationsScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<AnimationsScreen> createState() => _AnimationsScreenState();
}

class _AnimationsScreenState extends State<AnimationsScreen> {
  // Bools que determinan si la animación se ejecuta para entrar o salir
  bool animateFades = true;
  bool animateBounces = true;

  // DECLARO el customNotificationIcon, que es de la clase statefulW que menciono más adelante.
  NotificationIconAnimation customNotificationIcon = const NotificationIconAnimation();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Animation Screen"),
      ),
      drawer: const AppDrawer(),
      body: Column(
      
        // CÓDIGO
        
        Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              const Center(child: Text("Alarma"),),
              customNotificationIcon,
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // LLAMO al método triggerNotification y no me lo encuentra
                  customNotificationIcon.triggerNotification();
                }, 
                child: const Center(child: Text("Activar Alarma"))
              )]
          )

Este es el item Stateful que quiero usar de campana, con el método trigger para activarlo
import 'package:animate_do/animate_do.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NotificationIconAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  const NotificationIconAnimation({super.key});

  @override
  State<NotificationIconAnimation> createState() => _NotificationIconAnimationState();
}

class _NotificationIconAnimationState extends State<NotificationIconAnimation> {
  // Variable que indica si el icono tiene que estar vibrando
  bool isNotificationActive = false;

  void triggerNotification() {
    setState(() {
      isNotificationActive = true;
    });

    // Detener la vibración después de un tiempo.
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      setState(() {
        isNotificationActive = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ShakeX(
      animate: isNotificationActive, // Activa/desactiva la animación
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500), // Duración de cada vibración
      child: Icon(
        Icons.notifications,
        size: 80,
        color: isNotificationActive ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
      ),
    );
  }
}

Gracias por su tiempo

No puedes ocupar un metodo que este dentro de un widget, lo que se me ocurre hacer es que el widget NotificationIconAnimation , tambien tenga el ElevatedButton, y asi tener acceso a esa funcion.
Si lo quieres separados ya necesitarias un manejador de estado, provider bloc y manejar el estado de la animacion.

@Nagash Voy a intentar hacer lo que dices, que el valor de isNotificationActive  sea un Provider. Gracias por contestar!
